# Add a parameter at the end of link in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have created a project which is in two languages, french and english. when the select box is selected (english) the website language changes to english. Now i have a $language variable which is used in every function . I want to use it at the end of the url so that when someone selects english or french language the url would be `http://www. mydomain . com/index/eng`  .. but its `http://www. mydomain . com/index/` .. at the moment.. I also passed the variable in

```
 $this->load->view('site/index',$data);
```

like

```
 $this->load->view('site/index/'.$language,$data);
```

but I am getting

```
http:// mydomain .com / index / english.php
```

what to do ??

I have set routes also the controller is Site and function is index ..

Answer (score 1):

This language class extension allows you to automatically prefix all site urls with a language abbreviation that is pre-defined in your config file or from a link and automatically load the corresponding language translation file, the route will then be corrected by the route regex for everything to work as normal.

https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/wiki/URI-Language-Identifier